# What's the difference between these two arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am building a website. Every time I click to a "product" I want it to be saved in a react hook. Why does my program collapse when I use function2?

```
const function1 = prod => () => {...}
```

vs

```
const function2 = (prod) => {...}
```

```
const handlePurchase = prod => () => {
        setSelectedProduct(prod)
        history.push(`/product/?name=${prod.name}&id=${prod.id}`)
    }


    return (
        <>
            <h2 className="text-Header 1">Keep it Real Keep it Loco</h2>

            <ProductsContainer>
                {productsdb.map(prod => (
                    <div className="product" key={prod.id} onClick={handlePurchase(prod)}>
                        <img className="product-image" src={prod.img} alt={prod.name} />
                        <h2 className="product-name">{prod.name}</h2>
                        <h3 className="product-price">{'$' + prod.price}</h3>
                    </div>

                ))}
            </ProductsContainer>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any errors you are getting?

Comment: The first one is an arrow function that returns an arrow function. The second one might also be, we can't tell. But if the body `{...}` is the same for both, to switch from one to the other you'd also need to change where it's *used* (as should probably be anticipated), here to `onClick{() => handlePurchase(prod)}`.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. With function 1 the program works perfect. I just want to understand the difference between these 2 functions

Comment: What does "collapses" mean if *not* errors? Also if the first one works, why do you *want* to use the second one, especially if it doesn't work?

Comment: the body {...} its exactly the same. When i am using function2 the url gets crazy and i cant return to the home page "/".  When i am pressing the home button the url is the "/product/?name=${prod.name}&id=${prod.id}" even from other products that i didnt click

Comment: That's because without the function returning a function the *inner* code is immediately executed, rather than its execution being deferred until the button is clicked, and the *return value* gets passed as the click handler. Maybe just keep using the first one?

Comment: Okay got it, thank u!

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a function that returns another function, which is not executed right away

The second one is a regular function that happens right when it's called

Just change it to

```
const handlePurchase = prod => {...}
```